# ArcGIS: Adding labels to 2D FeatureLayer in JavaScript 3.25

Tags: arcgis-10.2, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is it possible to add labels to a 2D FeatureLayer in ArcGIS using the JavaScript 3.25 API. I can only find examples that use Javascript 4.8 and 3D scenes.

The following code doesn't show anything:

```
layer = new FeatureLayer("https://services3.arcgis.com/ntG7nrNunSl8x2gF/arcgis/rest/services/SmallAreasAgeRanges/FeatureServer/0", {
    "id": "0",
    "outFields": outFields,
    "showLabels": true,
    "labelingInfo": [{
    "labelExpressionInfo": {"value": "Abc"},
        "labelPlacement": "center-center",
        "symbol": new TextSymbol("Abc")
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet below shows how you should be labeling as of version 3.14 to 3.25

```
require(["esri/layers/LabelClass"], function(LabelClass) { /* code goes here */ });
```

Example:

```
//make sure the Map's showLabels option is set to true
var map = new Map("map", {
  basemap: "streets",
  center:[-80, 30],
  zoom: 5,
  showLabels : true
});

//create featurelayer
var flayer = new FeatureLayer(url, {
  outFields: ["*"] //make sure field to label is specified here in outFields
});


//create a text symbol and renderer to define the style of labels
var labelSymbol = new TextSymbol(); 

var json = {
  "labelExpressionInfo": {"value": "{LocalTime}"},
  "useCodedValues": false,
  "fieldInfos": [{fieldName: "LocalTime",format: { "dateFormat": "shortDate"}}]
};

//create instance of LabelClass
var lc = new LabelClass(json);
lc.symbol = labelSymbol; // symbol also can be set in LabelClass' json
flayer.setLabelingInfo([ lc ]);
```

For reference: [Link](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/labelclass-amd.html)

Comment: I had originally tried using the code from that reference page - before asking the question - and it didn't work. It turns out I had been setting 'showLabels' to true in the FeatureLayer not the Map object.